# how to display result where the object stored in multi dimension array PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, foreach

Result of a query stored in multi-dimension array, How to display these results in the view. The array example is as below.

[image: Multi-dimension array]

I am using laravel framework, using blade in view to display results.

I have tried foreach as below,

```
@foreach($adverts as $advert)
   @foreach($advert as $keyword)
     {{$keyword}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The above foreach didn't worked.
I would like to access all the elements under "keywords" in my view.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach($adverts as $advert)
   @foreach($advert->keywords as $keyword)
     {{$keyword}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck (please mark the answer as the right one ;) )

Comment: ismail I have noticed I am getting accumulative keywords from all element of array,